# Get count of one column from a table and count of same column matching in other table

Tags: mysql

I have two table as below

```
    table 1: raw
    dateCol id
1   01.01.2001 00:00:00 AAPL
2   02.01.2001 00:00:00 MSFT
3   03.01.2001 00:00:00 INFY

    table 2: universe
    udateCol    uid
1   01.01.2001 00:00:00 AAPL
2   02.01.2001 00:00:00 GOOGL
3   03.01.2001 00:00:00 INFY
```

i want to extract the count of ids from raw and count of ids from raw matching with uids in universe. So i tried the below query in Mysql:

```
select universe.udateCol, count(raw.id) as rawCount, count(universe.uid) as uniCount from universe left join raw on universe.udateCol = raw.dateCol AND raw.id = universe.uid group by universe.udateCol order by universe.udateCol;
```

using the above query, i'm getting the following output

```
    udateCol    rawCount    uniCount
1   01.01.2001 00:00:00 1   1
2   02.01.2001 00:00:00 0   1
3   03.01.2001 00:00:00 1   1
```

But i want the output to be like:

```
    udateCol    rawCount    uniCount
1   01.01.2001 00:00:00 1   1
2   02.01.2001 00:00:00 1   0
3   03.01.2001 00:00:00 1   1
```

If any one want to check live, then can check [here](http://rextester.com/live/VMT37437)

Edit1:

i want to get the count which exist in my raw table for each date, and count of those which are matching in universe table on the same date

Comment: Under what circumstances would raw count not be 1?

Comment: @Strawberry if there is no date in raw table on particular date, then it should be 0

Comment: @Strawberry didn't get you, what you tried to say? is this platform only for expert???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(A.dateCol) dateCol, COUNT(A.id) rawCount, COUNT(B.id) uniCount
FROM raw A LEFT JOIN universe B
ON A.id=B.uid AND DATE(A.dateCol)=DATE(B.udateCol)
GROUP BY DATE(A.dateCol);
```

Comment: it will not give the desired result

Comment: @ggupta obviously- because you didn't explain properly

Comment: @Strawberry - okay, i want to get the count which exist in my raw table for each date, and count of those which are matching in universe table on the same date. Hope this is clear now

Comment: @ggupta no. Contributors should not have to trawl through comments to figure out what's going on. EDIT YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: @ggupta If this answer addresses the question, then the question is still unclear.

Comment: Plus there is no A.udatecol, or b.id

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment, and a little tired of trying to draw blood from this stone...

Consider the following:

```
drop table if exists raw;
drop table if exists universe;

create table raw(dateCol date, id VARCHAR(20),PRIMARY KEY(datecol,id));
create table universe(udateCol date, uid VARCHAR(20),PRIMARY KEY(udatecol,uid));

insert into raw values
('20010101','AAPL'),
('20010102','MSFT'),
('20010103','INFY'),
('20010104','HOG');


insert into universe values
('20010101','AAPL'),
('20010102','GOOGL'),
('20010103','INFY'),
('20010105','HOG');
```

Note: I have made assumptions about the PRIMARY KEY in each case. If this is incorrect, please clarify.

Given this data set, what should the desired result look like? Think before you answer.